Hotlinking images from an S3 Bucket Object URL returning 404
I am aware you're not supposed to be embedding images using s3 object urls and instead should be using cloud front pointing to that. However, I came across a site who is doing that and the images are sporadically returning 404s in safari. When I go into developer console in safari, some don't have any info and others actually give me a request id which I then proceeded to look up using AWS Athena on s3 logs and it couldn't find it.
My question is. Do you know why embedding s3 image object urls would be sporadically failing? I was thinking it could be a throttling situation but I'm not sure.

What's wrong with using S3 object URLs? They are perfectly good to use without requiring CloudFront unless you have crazy volumes of requests. See: Best practices design patterns: optimizing Amazon S3 performance - Amazon Simple Storage Service

ok I stand corrected. Now I just need to figure out why I'm getting failed sporadic requests.

A 404 error means not found. Are you saying that a particular URL sometimes works and sometimes gives a 404, or are you saying that some specific URLs always give a 404?

I think it’s a safari issue. I noticed I’m getting the issue on some other sites. I noticed it on fandango recently. Strange this, my friend also sees the problem and he is on a separate network and MacBook Pro. @JohnRotenstein I have s3 images embedded on a site and they sporadically don’t Load in my browser. URL stays the same.

Yes, it sounds like a problem on your end.
